# Problem in enforcing case sensitivity in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am aware about MySQL being case insensitive by default.
I also read about using the collation utf8_general_cs to enable case sensitivity. But I get an error saying the collation is not identified. Also when I query the collation for charset utf8, the resultset shows ci related collations only. So question number 1 would be, do we need to configure cs related collations? If so, then I would like some guidance over it. Or is it dependent on some particular database engine?

Also I read about using utf8_bin collation for making MySQL queries search case sensitive. I did so. Set the schema collation as utf8_bin. But it didn't work. Restarted MySQL services as well to ensure that collation has been updated. But yet, when I do a

```
 Select * from table where name like 'el%';
```

It gives name starting from 'EL' as well.

Note: I am preferably looking for options to set the collation at the database level.
MySQL server version 5.6.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column collation has precedence over database and table collations. If you've been making changes, it's possible that your column is currently using the value that was the default when the table was created. You should be able to spot it with a proper SQL tool or by running:

```
SELECT table_schema, column_name, collation_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your database name'
AND table_name = 'your table name'
```

If you aren't willing to change the column collation, you can set it at expression level:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE bar LIKE 'el%' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
```

(demo)

Collation affects sorting and character comparison so you'll have to [read some docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html) to figure out which one suits your needs best (it isn't straightforward if you aren't a Unicode geek).

<sup>My projects are all in Spanish so I tend to use `utf8mb4_spanish_ci` a lot ;-)</sup>

Comment: Thanks alot for the heads up on the precedence part..I could get things working!

Answer (score 0):

I thought that normally worked?!
Anyway if this is a localised problem there are a few solutions:
Primarily one could use a `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name REGEXP '^[E][P]*$'` - regular expression.
The alternative
Surely you must be accessing this through another languages wrapper for either automation or handling rather than the MySQL console right? I would suggest sorting it using the language you’re using for a wrapper this can easily be implemented. Still however only deal with those beginning in `el` as this will reduce the number of things to check.

Comment: Hey..I am using hibernate to write my queries.. basically the criteria queries..so yes regular expression could be used..but it would make code dirty right..and I want the table data to be case sensitive across all the tables in the schema because the unique values wouldn't be unique if data is case insensitive..like for instance registeration id a101 and A101 both would be allowed..again just an example..so I need the database data to be case sensitive

Comment: Then surely this is fixed on application - check if it’s in the stuff, if it isn’t then you’re good to go, else you aren’t. But what I suggest here is using an id that is set uniquely by the MySQL server - increments every time - and having a field for email or username (obviously check this) then now you wouldn’t have different ids then for username safety - making sure they’re the same you could use the username and the Id like discord? Other then that I haven’t a clue. I still don’t understand why just checking the results of the query wouldn’t work?..